# Neither user nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I know it may be silly question and I have referred all the similar question before but unfortunately I could resolve this issue. Most probably it is problem in my Manifest.xml file.

When I am trying to access location, app is crashing

here is my manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.tt.test" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".sTest"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.test.tt.test.sService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter> </service>
    <service android:name="com.test.tt.test.sServiceRequest" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />


</application>
```

when I run it throw this error

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 11029 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.
```

Similar with other permissions. I can not see any mistake in my manifest file. Help appreciated

Comment: Requested permissions go outside of the `<application>` tags.

Comment: i already tried by putting outisde application tag

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This means you have some wrong information or malformed info in your menifest file and that is the reason none of your Permission is not identified by your app. Just make sure you have cleaned ANDROIDMANIFEST file with any malformed data.

It will work and all permission should be outside Application tag

Comment: Yes, it was this : "all permission should be outside Application tag".

Answer (score 15):

If you are running on a device on Android Marshmallow and above:

If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher and if the app's target SDK is 23 or higher, the app not just have to list the permissions in the manifest but also must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running.

More info:

http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

and

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: @user1147688 The first link has the example on how to request permission at the run time.

Answer (score 3):

move the uses-permission outside application just below the manifest tag

Answer (score 3):

Moving permission section solved my problem with "Neither user or current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE". Thank you so much to everyone in this forum.
In reference to others, my changes are bellow:

**Original:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <activity android:name=".NfcRead"></activity>
</application>
```

**Change:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
        android:required="true" />

    <activity android:name=".NfcRead"></activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is related to the runtime permission system in Android 6 and above. The Location permission comes under dangerous permission [[check here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)], so you must have to fulfill below 2 minimum requirements to handle these permissions:

1. Declared below 2 permission in manifest (These permissions must be outside application tag)

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />  
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION " />
   ```
2. Check for the granted permission at runtime using ***checkSelfPermission()*** and request permissions using ***requestPermissions()*** if not already granted.

If you have already done both of the above then and still getting error then check below:

1. You App's **targetSdkVersion** (should be >=23) [If the application's targetSdkVersion is set to less than 23. It will be assumed that application is not tested with new permission system yet and will switch to the same old behavior: user has to accept every single permission at install time and they will be all granted once installed].
2. Check if you have any thing wrong with you manifest file. You might have malformed manifest file.
3. Check if you are calling any function, that works on location data, before the user Accept/revoked runtime location permission dialog?
4. Clean you app (Clean build) and re-run.

Hope this may help :-)