# Neither user nor current process has android.permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

There are quite a few questions regarding similar issues:

> Neither user nor current process has
>   android.permission.SOME_PERMISSION

The only thing that varies between the questions is the `SOME_PERMISSION`.  I did not forget the permission in the AndroidManifest or misspell it. The APK works on my device but on the customer's device it causes the issue.
Potentially relevant information: LG device, Android OS version 6.0.1, my app is a system/priv-app/ with 644 permissions.

I specifically want to know how can this error be reliably reproduced? 
`SOME_PERMISSION` can represent a number of different permissions. This is not a dangerous permission and I am aware of how to handle permission in Android 6+ with targetSDK 23.

Comment: Then give an example not `SOME_PERMISSION` ... from the question that you post the only reason is runtime permissions ... or permission which google makes `system/signature`

Comment: I specifically wanted to make the point that there a lot of different permissions this can happen with. I did not want to give a specific permission cause then people would redirect me to a specific thread and none of them have a scenario for reproducing. My specific crash happens with ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

Comment: Now it's something ... it's a bug/feature in LG's OS modification ... it can revoke this permission

Comment: @Selvin Do you have some information or a source I can read up on this and suggest a fix?

Comment: sorry, I don't ... I had simillar issue and did some research over the internet long time ago

Comment: I've added the information. Thanks

Comment: @Selvin can you maybe add some more information regarding what it is that you found? So I can go looking in the right direction.

Comment: This exception is related to the runtime permission system in Android 6 and above. Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56751985/5685911