# uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK permission issue

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-7.0-nougat

i am using this permission in my app and working fine in all devices and also in `Marhshmallow 6.0` device.

There no need to `WAKE_LOCK` permission runtime because its normal permission but getting issue in `Nougat 7.0` devices.

**App getting crashed and error occur `"java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10799 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"` on line `wakelock.acquire();`**

How to fix that?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312733/neither-user-nor-current-process-has-android-permission-access-coarse-location).

Comment: could you post your androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Exactly your `manifest.xml` must contain malformed information

Comment: Share your code Manifest file

Comment: post your Manifest file

Comment: azizbekian .....u are right ..actually issue was in manifest file ..and now resolved and working properly ..thanx to all

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

only, no extra code needed.
    Call **acquire()** to acquire the wake lock and force the device to stay on at the level that was requested when the wake lock was created.

Call **release()** when you are done and don't need the lock anymore. It is very important to do this as soon as possible to avoid running down the device's battery excessively.

**Add all the uses-permission at the end of the manifest**

Comment: This doesn't help on 8.0 Android emulator, also placing `uses-permission` after `application` is useless. I get `unable to acquire wakeLock`, `SecurityException: Neither user 10085 nor current process has android.permission.WAKE_LOCK`.

Comment: I get this error only in the emulator with API 30. In another emulator with API 26 it does not occur.

Answer (score 6):

Find the solution

As per my knowledge this is enough in Manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

For Screen continously ON write below logic

```
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: No need for asking `WAKE_LOCK ` permission.

Comment: I think this is enough  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>  If it is dangerous permission just write above logic

Comment: WAKE_LOCK has a normal priority, not dangerous.

Comment: I think you have declared permission inside application, Please check once.

Comment: I'm not the OP :-)

Comment: May i know for what purpose are you using this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138781/discussion-between-rajasekhar-and-azizbekian).

Answer (score -1):

You have ask for the permission at run time:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK},
                REQUEST_PERMISSION);

    }


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @NonNull final int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission granted.
        } else {
            // User refused to grant permission.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No need for asking `WAKE_LOCK` permission.